# Como ordenar pelos resultados mais similares ao parâmetro passado?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp-3

Tenho uma tabela no meu sistema que guarda todos os aeroportos e em um *`select autocomplete`* eu tenho essa lista onde eu posso pesquisar.

O problema é que eu posso pesquisar por "`nome`", "`cidade`", "`país`" e "`IATA`" e preciso **`retornar em ordem de mais similar`** os aeroportos encontrados.

Por exemplo:

meu parâmetro é "`GRU`" e a função me retorna isto:

```
{
    "airports": [
        {
            "id": 1059,
            "iata": "BPA",
            "full_name": "Grumman, Bethpage, Bethpage, (BPA)"
        },
        {
            "id": 3410,
            "iata": "GUU",
            "full_name": "Bakki, Grundarfjordur, Grundarfjordur, (GUU)"
        },
        {
            "id": 8083,
            "iata": "GRU",
            "full_name": "Guarulhos, São Paulo, São Paulo, (GRU)"
        }
    ],
}
```

Como podem ver, o retorno está certo, mas eu, como usuário, pesquisei o IATA e a função me retornou tudo que fosse parecido com o que eu pesquisei.

O código é o seguinte:

```
$str_where = "CITEXT(
                            TRANSLATE(
                                TRIM(
                                    name || ', ' || city || ', ' || country || ', ' || '(' || iata || ')' 
                                ) , 
                                'áàâãäåaaaÁÂÃÄÅAAAÀéèêëeeeeeEEEÉEEÈìíîïìiiiÌÍÎÏÌIIIóôõöoooòÒÓÔÕÖOOOùúûüuuuuÙÚÛÜUUUUçÇñÑýÝ',
                                'aaaaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAeeeeeeeeeEEEEEEEiiiiiiiiIIIIIIIIooooooooOOOOOOOOuuuuuuuuUUUUUUUUcCnNyY'
                            )
                        )";

            $airports = $connection
                    ->newQuery()
                    ->select(['id', 'iata'])
                    ->select(["CITEXT(name || ', ' || city || ', ' || country || ', ' || '(' || iata || ')' ) AS full_name"])
                    ->from('white_label_airports')
                    ->where([$str_where . ' LIKE' => '%' . \Cake\Utility\Text::transliterate($this->request->data('term')) . '%'])
                    ->limit(20)
                    ->execute()
                    ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Gostaria de saber se tenho como ordenar pelo mais similar dentre a resposta do servidor e se alguém tem alguma ideia melhor.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: No Oracle uso a Jaro Winkler e/ou a EDIT_DISTANCE  , para Postgreesql no Google achei isto https://gist.github.com/fjavier/586c713943d76a023a70 , eu uso para buscar strings por "proximidade" veja se ajuda

Comment: Bem interessante essa implementação, eu nem fazia idéia de como funcionavam os algoritmos de similaridade entre strings! Ainda assim sugiro o uso do pg_trgm por ser uma solução "nativa" do Postgres, que suporta indexação por similaridade e tudo o mais, hehe...

Answer (score 0):

Para classificar esse array você precisa de um índice de similaridade que lhe diga que Guarulhos é a "melhor resposta" dos três, algo que tem que ser retornado pelo servidor que te disse que esses são os resultados mais similares...

### **Usando pg_trgm**

Com PostgreSQL eu usaria o módulo [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html), que te retorna tal índice e já permite classificar com `ORDER BY` direto na consulta, poupando qualquer trabalho extra no PHP. Para fins de exemplo, criei uma tabela "aeroportos" com os três registros que você mostrou:

```
create table aeroportos (id int not null, iata text not null, full_name text not null);
insert into aeroportos values 
(1059, 'BPA', 'Grumman, Bethpager, Bethpage, (BPA)'),
(3419, 'GUU', 'Bakki, Grundarfjorfur, Grundarfjordur, (GUU)'),
(8083, 'GRU', 'Guarulhos, São Paulo, (GRU)');
```

Aqui podemos usar a função `word_similarity()`, que retorna o grau de similaridade entre uma string e a palavra mais parecida com ela em outra string. Quanto maior o valor na coluna `grau` (de 0 a 1), maior a similaridade entre as strings.
Note que concatenei as colunas `iata` e `full_name` para comparar com "GRU" como uma coisa só.

```
select *, word_similarity(iata||full_name, 'GRU') as grau 
from aeroportos 
order by grau desc;

  id  | iata |                  full_name                   |   grau   
------+------+----------------------------------------------+----------
 8083 | GRU  | Guarulhos, São Paulo, (GRU)                  | 0.166667
 3419 | GUU  | Bakki, Grundarfjordur, Grundarfjordur, (GUU) |    0.125
 1059 | BPA  | Grumman, Bethpager, Bethpage, (BPA)          | 0.047619
(3 rows)
```

**Detalhando um pouco mais...**

Como a sua tabela certamente possui mais do que três registros, é interessante utilizar também operadores de similaridade para filtrar somente aqueles que se pareçam o suficiente com a sua busca, senão toda consulta retornará a lista inteira de aeroportos, na maioria com similaridade '0.0'. Você pode simplesmente usar LIMIT e cortar na quantidade de registros que lhe for mais conveniente, mas pode também usar outras funcionalidades do PostgreSQL para filtrar por similaridade, algo que te dará muito mais desempenho para grandes volumes de dados se somado ao uso de índices GIST.

Para isso podemos usar o operador (que também faz parte do pacote pg_trgm) `<%` na cláusula `WHERE`. Esse operador retorna `true` caso o primeiro parâmetro seja uma string que contenha palavra similar ao segundo parâmetro, desde que o grau de similaridade de palavra seja maior do que o limite mínimo especificado pela opção `pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold`. Como já notamos pela query anterior, o grau geral de similaridade de nossas comparações é geralmente baixo, já que a "resposta certa" para GRU tem uma pontuação de somente 0.16. Assim, devemos baixar o limitador mínimo para que o nosso `WHERE` não retorne zero registros. Quanto menor for o `pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold`, mais registros serão retornados:

```
set pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold to 0.1;

select *, word_similarity(iata||full_name, 'GRU') as grau 
from aeroportos 
where (iata||full_name) <% 'GRU' 
order by grau desc;

  id  | iata |                  full_name                   |   grau   
------+------+----------------------------------------------+----------
 8083 | GRU  | Guarulhos, São Paulo, (GRU)                  | 0.166667
 3419 | GUU  | Bakki, Grundarfjordur, Grundarfjordur, (GUU) |    0.125
(2 rows)
```

Definido todo esse curso de ação, no PHP a coisa fica simples. É só mandar o `SET` para o limite mínimo de similaridade junto com a query:

```
$query = "set pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold to 0.1; select *, word_similarity(iata||full_name, 'GRU') as grau from aeroportos where (iata||full_name) <% 'GRU' order by grau desc;";
$res = pg_query($conn, $query);
```

Ou ainda, caso não queira passar toda vez o limitador, pode inclusive fixá-lo como propriedade do usuário da sua aplicação:

```
alter user nunks set pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold = 0.1;
select usename, useconfig from pg_user where usename = 'nunks';
 usename |                useconfig                
---------+-----------------------------------------
 nunks   | {pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold=0.1}
(1 row)
```

---

### **Instalando a extensão pg_trgm**

Caso você não tenha o pg_trgm instalado, use o comando `CREATE EXTENSION`:

```
> create extension pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Caso o comando falhe você provavalmente precisa instalar o pacote de extensões [postgresql-contrib](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/contrib.html), que pode tanto ser compilado quanto instalado a partir do gerenciador de pacotes de sua escolha. No Windows, o instalador gráfico te dá opção de quais módulos contrib instalar.

Além da função `word_similarity()` que utilizamos aqui, a extensão `pg_trgm` oferece outras funcionalidades associadas, como [índices GIN e GIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly) capazes de agilizar bastante a resposta de buscas por similaridade em grandes volumes de dados, operadores especiais e métodos para ajuste fino dos valores limite de similaridade.